# Regex to match a word following spaces and numbers

Tags: regex

I have searched around quite a bit, but I haven't found a solution for my problem yet.

I'm trying to create a regex that will allow me to match the following examples:

```
YOUU 410831 0
MEIU 810851 0
```

I got to `\b(YOUU|MEIU)\w*\b`.

But then I can't seem to add a space, then a number, then a space again, and finally a digit. How could I achieve this?

Comment: try `\b(YOUU|MEIU) \d+ \d\b`

Comment: `\b(YOUU|MEIU)\w*\b\s+\d+\s+\d`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are looking for something like

```
[A-Z]+(?:\s+[0-9]+)+
```

[See demo](https://regex101.com/r/vR3pY0/1)

Or, if there are 2 set groups of numbers after the word, and the 1st number is 6 digits in size, and the last digit is always of size 1:

```
[A-Z]+\s+[0-9]{6}\s+[0-9]\b
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/vR3pY0/3)

With `i` option, the words with lowercase letters will also be matched.

Answer (score 1):

You are probably looking for this regex?

```
\b(YOUU|MEIU)\s+\d+\b\s+\d
```

if the numbers in the middle are always 6 numbers, you may want to fix that with

```
\b(YOUU|MEIU)\s+\d{6}\b\s+\d
```

Comment: Shouldn't `\w*` be `\d+`?

Comment: The question says _a space, then the **number**, then a space again_.

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this:

```
\b(YOUU|MEIU) \d+ \d\b
```

**[REGEX DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/lR5aW1/1)**